# How to manage wordpress plugins outside wp-admin?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a client and I made his website using wordpress. I am using the plugin "Ultimate Member" and I want to enable my client to approve User Registrations without ever accessing the wp-admin panel.

Comment: It's not adding my tag of "wordpress-plugin". I don't know why.

Comment: If you don't want your client to ever see the WP Dashboard, you'll need to create a simple interface for this. This interface would need to talk with WordPress somehow, I think the [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) would be a good option.

Comment: It is also possible to have a very restricted WP Dashboard by creating a user role with a restricted set of capabilities. If I remember correctly the menu items will not be shown if the role of the logged in user does not have the corresponding capability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it by [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/)

OR simple create a page where fetch all those pending user listig with joining of table.
then show listing add one button APPROVE or REJECT. On that button click fire post method and change status of that list.